# Wrong Duration Timing shown for audio in ios but correct in android flutter app

Tags: flutter, audio, avaudioplayer, duration, content-length

I have a audio file of `04:06` mins and this timing is only shown in android version app of flutter project. But in the iOS version, the issue is that the duration is `doubled` or `more than double`. Using the `audio player` plugin from the flutter. Is this something related to package or it's an issue with iOS itself?

Note: the ios version of the audio file when played, don't repeat the audio. when it reaches the `04:06 mins` mark, the audio stops but the progress for the indicator continues till end and so its like the song is still playing.

**Update**

In the end I closed the simulator and opened it again and it was magically working. I guess that there was a minor bug around.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I m also having some problems with the duration of a file in iOS (in my case way lower)

Comment: I don't have access to the project any more but was not able to get it working as much as I remember. one solution I can give is cancel / stop it by adding a listerner for the length of the audio.